# Mod Factorio - an attempt to turn off the music while the game is running

Tags: lua

I'm trying to write a mod that adds music to the game. Just add music is obtained through the data.lua file

here is the code (data.lua):

```lua
require("music.gameplay.gameplay")
require("music.rock.rock")
require("music.starcraft.starcraft")
```

these are albums - each has a file that adds music via "data:extend"

There are no problems here, everything works. But I would like to implement such a feature - the ability to disable a certain album in the game settings (mod settings)

I created a button in the "settings.lua" file

here is the code (settings.lua):

```lua
data:extend({
    {
        type = "string-setting",
        name = "my-mod-always-difficult",
        setting_type = "runtime-global",
        default_value = "yes",
        allowed_values = {"yes", "no"}
    }
})
```

And from this moment the problems begin.
I tried to add music when starting the game in the same "data.lua" file with the condition.

```lua
if settings.global["my-mod-always-difficult"].value == "yes" then
    require("music.randFT.gameplay.gameplay")
    require("music.randFT.rock.rock")
    require("music.randFT.starcraft.starcraft")
end
```

returns an error: attempt to index field 'global' (a nil value)

then I decided to delete the tracks during the map launch in the "control.lua" file:
here is the code (settings.lua):

```lua
local function removeAddedMusic()
  for i, sound in ipairs(data.raw["ambient-sound"]) do
    if sound.name ~= "Terran_1" then
      table.remove(data.raw["ambient-sound"], i)
    end
  end
end

script.on_init(removeAddedMusic)
```

tried to delete all but one music - "Terran_1"
another mistake: factorio attempt to index global 'data' (a nil value)

I understand that I use to "data" and "global" at the moment when they have the value "nil"
but how to do otherwise, I don't understand

I tried to do a couple more actions, but the same trouble, the same mistakes.

Comment: Seems like you can make a setting of `setting_type = 'startup'` which can be accessed in the data stage via `settings.startup`. I think a runtime setting fundamentally can't control whether or not something is added to `data`, so if a runtime setting would have to control the music in a different way (but I'm not sure if any such way exists).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just `settings["my-mod-always-difficult"].value` without the global.

Then your `removeAddedMusic` function would need to be in the data stage, as the control stage can no longer modify the data global.